# Como coloco un h3 arriba de varios div centrados

Tags: html, css, html5

Tengo varios div centrados y para ello he colocado este codigo en mi div contenedor.

**Codigo HTML:**

```
<div class="b_container">
  <div class="Zona" >
     <h3>Por Zona</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="Enti" >
      <h3>Por Entidad</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="person" >
    <h3>Por Persona</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="Top" >
    <h3>TOP 5 DE ENTIDAD</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Codigo CSS:**

```
.b_container {
   padding: 10%;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Quiero poner un titulo arriba de estos div y dentro del contenedor. Justo en el cuador rojo como se ve en la imagen.
[image: En la linea roja quiero poner un h3]

Sin embargo, el h3 que quiero colocar irá en ese cuadro rojo, pero al colocar un h3 se alinea con los div.
[image: Foto del error]
¿Comó puedo centrar mi h3 para que este encima de los div sin ser afectado por el display?

Comment: Prueba a encapsular los contenedores en un div y que el titulo quede fuera de ese div (antes para ser concreto), si pones el código html puedo elaborarte una respuesta mas concreta.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo actualice con el HTML

Answer (score 2):

para el h3 pordes usar la propiedad [Flex basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) que aplica un tamaño inicial de un elemento flexible que de manera predeterminada es `auto` , pero esto solo no alcanza sino que tenes que hacer que los elementos puedan caerse y no obligarlos a permanecer en una sola linea esto lo haces con [Flex-wrap](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/) son su valor en `wrap`, ahora solo resta decirle al texto de `h3` que se alinea al centro con `text-align`

```css
.box {
width:100px;
height:50px;
background-color:aqua;
margin:10px;
border:1px solid black
}

.b_container {
   
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-wrap:wrap
}

h3{
flex-basis:100%;
text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div class="b_container">
  <h3>centrado del contenedor</h3>
  <div class="box" >
    
  </div>
  <div class="box" >
       
  </div>
  <div class="box" >
   
  </div>
  <div class="box" >
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Comentarios:

- Seguro lo estás tratando de colocar antes del **`div`** zona
- Se te coloca en fila igual que el resto de los divs por acción del **`display flex`** que distribuye inicialmente a todos los elementos de izquierda a derecha sobre el eje horizontal
- Los **`h#`** son elementos en bloque así que una salida es que lo coloques fuera del div con ID  **`b_container`** y con eso queda acomodado como esperas
- La otra es que:

  - Coloca los cuatro divs en un contenedor y deja al título fuera de este contenedor
  - Al contenedor principal que en este caso sería **`<div class="b_container">`** deberás

    - Dejarlo sin alguna clase de propiedades y valores de flex
    - Ahora al div que contiene a zona, entidad, mes y top nuevamente dale un **`display flex`** para que esté solo afecte nuevamente a sus hijos internos y los distribuya en fila

Código:

CSS

```
.b_container {
    padding: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}
#resto{
    display: flex;
}
```

Y ahora tu HTML

```
<div class="b_container">
    <h3>hola</h3>
<div id="resto">
<div class="Zona" >
     <h3>Por Zona</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="Enti" >
      <h3>Por Entidad</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="person" >
    <h3>Por Persona</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="Top" >
    <h3>TOP 5 DE ENTIDAD</h3>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Ahora podrías centrar horizontalmente el **`h3`** sin comprometer a los demás elementos.

**Ejemplo completo**

```html
    <style>
    .b_container {
       border: 1px solid crimson;
       width: 100%;
    }
    #resto{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    h3 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    
    <div class="b_container">
      <h3>hola</h3>
      <div id="resto">
        <div class="Zona" >
          <h3>Por Zona</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="Enti" >
          <h3>Por Entidad</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="person" >
          <h3>Por Persona</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="Top" >
          <h3>TOP 5 DE ENTIDAD</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Eliminé la otra respuesta tratando de ofrecer otra mas simple ya que estaba siendo redundante en la forma de acomodar al título y estaba desaprovechando lo que en su propia naturaleza ya ofrecen las etiquetas **`h#`**

Answer (score 1):

Simple, crea un contenedor genérico `<div>` arriba de `b_container` y luego otro arriba de este último para encapsular todo:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.b_container {
   padding: 0.5rem;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}

.b_container div {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0 0.05rem;
  border: 2px solid darkgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title_container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="title_container">
    <h2>El titulo va aqui</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="b_container">
    <div class="Zona">
      <h3>Por Zona</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="Enti">
      <h3>Por Entidad</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
      <h3>Por Persona</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="Top">
      <h3>TOP 5 DE ENTIDAD</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```